# Django Sort by backward foreign key

Tags: django, django-queryset

I currently have the following models

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
      creator = models.ForeignKey('User') # points to the initial user

class Message(models.Model):
      room = models.ForeignKey('ChatRoom')
      text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      date = models.DateTimeField()
      from = models.ForeignKey('User') # points to some user
```

For any given user who logs into my website, I want to display a list of the chat rooms they have created, ordered by the date of their last message (latest activity) along with the last message entered to the chatroom

So something like

```
Your chat rooms
---------------
science - "hey guys, anyone know how to do calculus?" 5m
art     - "hey guys, I like art" 10m
```

How would I perform this query in django? Keep in mind that a person might have many, many, many chat rooms and thus we can't just load all the chat_rooms with `ChatRoom.objects.all()` and manually iterate through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a additional relation to your last message, otherwise you will not be able to order by them.

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
      creator = models.ForeignKey('User') # points to the initial user
      # you will need to set this in view or with signals.(don't forget to handle delete)
      last_message = models.ForignKey('Message')
```

And that you can do this

```
ChatRoom.objects.filter(...).order_by('last_message__date')
```

Comment: So are you saying that without this foreign key, there is literally no possible way to order by them unless I specifically get them with `all()` and manually do iterate through it?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to order, but this is not only about ordering part. Also this will help you with rendering of last message. Because without this. you will have to separately get last message for each `CharRoom`

Comment: What are your thoughts on a foreign key `last message` vs just straight up setting duplicates e.g. `last_message_date` & `last_message_text`

Comment: @Alan It is possibility too. But FK is more general solution. Because, then one day you will want to add `last_message_username`, `last_message_tags` etc. And the way you will set this data is same so I don't see the reason to denormalize is here.