# How to annotate field by filer from manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django

my models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    m2mStatus = models.ManyToManyField("ProjectStatus")

class ProjectStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    startTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to annotate like this:

```
pj = Project.objects.filter(name="abc")
ps = pj.m2mStatus.last()
Project.objects.filter(name="abc").annotate(status=ps.status)
```

any help ?

Comment: second line `ps = pj.m2mStatus.last()` won't work because it is not an instance of Project it is queryset. Can explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: A Project has many ProjectStatus, i want to select all project with  last projectstatus

Comment: It will be better to use this approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40169399/3627387