# When saving Django models that have cyclical foreign keys, how to save all at once?

Tags: python, django

I currently have the following models. Both `Chat` and `Message` have references to each other.

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    id   = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    subject      = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    last_message = models.OneToOneField(to='Message',
                                        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                        related_name='last_chat')

class Message(models.Model):
    id   = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    chat = models.ForeignKey(to='Chat',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user = models.ForeignKey(to='accounts.User',
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

The problem is, in order to create a new chat room, I will have to insert both a new `Chat` object and at least one new `Message` object.

But since they both reference each other, inserting either first without the other will cause a ForeignKey constraint error and crash.

How do I solve this? Should I delay the enforcement of foreign key constraints until after I have saved both? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Try making the `last_message` nullable by adding `blank=True, null=True`.

Comment: @Selcuk But I dont want it to be nullabe, notice `on_delete=models.PROTECT`

Comment: The referential integrity in your database won't allow you to do this. You should allow it to become null, then populate it after saving the `Chat` object. Alternatively, you can keep a dummy `Message` object in your database to use as the initial value.

Comment: There is a way to do this. But it is little hacky. It will be better if you make `last_message` nullable. Your users can't create chat without creating message?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev so basically, I insert everything with null values and update them once their in the table?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save) signal for setting last message. First we need to make `last_message` nullable.

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    id   = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    subject      = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    last_message = models.OneToOneField(to='Message', null=True,
                                        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                        related_name='last_chat')
class Message(models.Model):
    ...

# example of signal
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def set_last_message(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Chat.objects.filter(id=instance.chat_id).update(last_message=instance)

# in your controller code
chat = Chat.objects.create(...)
Message.objects.create(chat=chat, ...) # so your last_message will be set on this line
```

**NOTE(31.01.20):**

This could be achieved in newer django version without denormalization via `Window` function https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Answer (score 2):

The problem as you say is that you have a circular relationship. But I don't think you need it; the `last_message` field is unnecessary, since you can always query the last message by doing `chat.message_set.order_by('date').last()`.

Comment: This denormalization is needed because he needs to query chats with last messages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169203/django-sort-by-backward-foreign-key